# Resources for Difficult Highschool Maths Problems

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I want a resource or recommendations for where I can get difficult Mathematical problems.

This problems must be really difficult and require extremely substantial intellectual prowess to solve.

I would also love a way for me to verify my answers of course, I would prefer if workings are shown with the answer result.

Catch though: The problems must not use more than High School Mathematics (once again -Calculus).

Uhmmm In my country in High School there was a Basic Maths curriculum, and an extended Maths curriculum. Calculus, Algebra, and Cambridge A level Pure Mathematics were part of the extended curriculum.

The rest was part of the Basic curriculum.

I would like for the questions I attempt to only require basic curriculum knowledge. (For certain reasons, I never really learned Calculus until now; only learned Integration on Tuesday, and could get by with Differentiation.

Limits, Fundamental theorem of Calculus, etc I all plan on internalising soon).

So difficult problems, that only require Basic High School Mathematics.

Comment: Google [IMO Questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22IMO+Questions%22)

Comment: I think Art of Problem Solving forums are a gold standard: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community

Comment: See this question: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/8342/challenge-questions-for-extremely-bright-kids/8343 I'd add to that list *Problems in Plane Geometry* and *Problems in Solid Geometry* by Sharygin, *Higher Algebra* by Ferrar, *Advanced Algebra* by Durell and Robson, *Higher Course Geometry* by Forder.